# Alterar conteúdo das linhas em Python

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um dataframe que contém diversas colunas com id para indicar as categorias das variáveis.
Como faço pra substituir esses ids pelas categorias?

*View do data frame:*

[image: Data Frame:]

*Dicionário:*

```
sexo = {
    0: 'Masculino', 
    1: 'Feminino'
}
cor = {
    0: 'Indígena', 
    2: 'Branca', 
    4: 'Preta', 
    6: 'Amarela', 
    8: 'Parda', 
    9: 'Sem declaração'
}
anos_de_estudo = {
    1: 'Sem instrução e menos de 1 ano', 
    2: '1 ano', 
    3: '2 anos', 
    4: '3 anos', 
    5: '4 anos', 
    6: '5 anos', 
    7: '6 anos', 
    8: '7 anos', 
    9: '8 anos', 
    10: '9 anos', 
    11: '10 anos', 
    12: '11 anos', 
    13: '12 anos', 
    14: '13 anos', 
    15: '14 anos', 
    16: '15 anos ou mais', 
    17: 'Não determinados'
}
uf = {
    11: 'Rondônia', 
    12: 'Acre', 
    13: 'Amazonas', 
    14: 'Roraima', 
    15: 'Pará', 
    16: 'Amapá', 
    17: 'Tocantins', 
    21: 'Maranhão', 
    22: 'Piauí', 
    23: 'Ceará', 
    24: 'Rio Grande do Norte', 
    25: 'Paraíba', 
    26: 'Pernambuco', 
    27: 'Alagoas', 
    28: 'Sergipe', 
    29: 'Bahia', 
    31: 'Minas Gerais', 
    32: 'Espírito Santo', 
    33: 'Rio de Janeiro', 
    35: 'São Paulo', 
    41: 'Paraná', 
    42: 'Santa Catarina', 
    43: 'Rio Grande do Sul', 
    50: 'Mato Grosso do Sul', 
    51: 'Mato Grosso', 
    52: 'Goiás', 
    53: 'Distrito Federal'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o método `map` de uma série do Pandas (isto é, uma coluna do DataFrame) para mapear valores conforme um dicionário, onde a chave representa o valor atual da coluna, e o valor associado à chave é o valor de "destino" da sua nova coluna.

Exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

frutas = {
    0: 'maçã',
    1: 'banana',
    2: 'abacaxi',
    3: 'uva',
}

vendas = pd.DataFrame({
    'dia': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'],
    'id_fruta': [0, 2, 1, 2],
    'quantidade': [3, 1, 1, 2],
})
print(vendas)
# output:
#           dia  id_fruta  quantidade
# 0  2021-01-01         0           3
# 1  2021-01-01         2           1
# 2  2021-01-02         1           1
# 3  2021-01-03         2           2

vendas['fruta'] = vendas['id_fruta'].map(frutas)  # criando nova coluna
print(vendas)
# output:
#           dia  id_fruta  quantidade    fruta
# 0  2021-01-01         0           3     maçã
# 1  2021-01-01         2           1  abacaxi
# 2  2021-01-02         1           1   banana
# 3  2021-01-03         2           2  abacaxi
```

Portanto, no seu caso basta aplicar o método `map` às colunas de interesse (note que vou sobrescrevê-las - use nomes diferentes para as colunas novas caso isso seja indesejado):

```
dados['Sexo'] = dados['Sexo'].map(sexo)
dados['Cor'] = dados['Cor'].map(cor)
dados['Anos de Estudo'] = dados['Anos de Estudo'].map(anos_de_estudo)
dados['UF'] = dados['UF'].map(uf)
```

Ou de forma ligeiramente menos repetitiva usando um for loop:

```
for nome_coluna, mapa in [
    ('Sexo', sexo),
    ('Cor', cor),
    ('Anos de Estudo', anos_de_estudo),
    ('UF', uf),
]:
    dados[nome_coluna] = dados[nome_coluna].map(mapa)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assim como foi apresentado pelo nosso colega *jfaccioni* a utilização do map, vou apresentar uma abordagem um pouco diferente utilizando o método [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) do pandas.

**Exemplo** - dict-like `to_replace`:

```py
import pandas as pd

sexo = {0: 'Masculino', 1: 'Feminino'}
cor = {0: 'Indígena', 1: 'Branca', 2: 'Preta'}
uf = {11: 'Rondônia', 12: 'Acre', 13: 'Amazonas'}

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'uf': [11, 12, 13],
   'sexo': [1, 1, 0],
   'cor': [0, 1, 2],
   'idade': [20, 23, 30]
})

print(df)
#          Output
#    uf  sexo  cor  idade
# 0  11     1    0     20
# 1  12     1    1     23
# 2  13     0    2     30
#
```

Aplicando então o *replace* no dataframe o resultado vai ser:

```py
df = df.replace({'sexo': sexo, 'cor': cor, 'uf': uf})

#          uf       sexo       cor  idade
# 0  Rondônia   Feminino  Indígena     20
# 1      Acre   Feminino    Branca     23
# 2  Amazonas  Masculino     Preta     30
```

Enfim, o método replace é bem poderoso e não apenas se restringe a dicionários. Podemos utilizar em listas, expressões regulares, pandas series e muitas outras.

**Referências**:

1. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html